# unfortunately, the project has stopped, android error

Tags: android

I am writing an android application, the application has many buttons each button will direct the user to another activity, the problem is when I run the application it crashes.

it just says:  unfortunately, the project has stopped.

I don't know what may cause this problem!!

this is the main activity I am using :

```
public class MainActivity extends DashActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         setHeader(getString(R.string.HomeTitle), true);
    }


     public void onButtonClicker(View v)
        {
            Intent intent;

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.hotels_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, Hotels.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.restaurants_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, Restaurants.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.airports_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, Airports.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.currency_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, Currency.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.praytime_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, PrayTime.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.about_bt:
                intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;  
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

here is one of the other activities: just for testing :

```
public class Airports extends DashActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.airports);
        setHeader(getString(R.string.airports), true);

    }
}
```

and here is the main.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

      <!-- Included header.xml here -->
    <ViewStub android:id="@+id/vsHeader" 
        android:inflatedId="@+id/header" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout="@layout/header" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hotels_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:layout_width="122dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/hotel"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/hotels" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/restaurants_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/restaurant"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/restaurants" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/airports_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/airport"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/airports" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/currency_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/dollar"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button android:id="@+id/praytime_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/praytime"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/mosque"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/about_bt"
            style="@style/home_button"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicker"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/about"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the logcat:

```
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     ... 11 more
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.dashboard_our/com.example.dashboard_our.Hotels}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     at com.example.dashboard_our.MainActivity.onButtonClicker(MainActivity.java:24)
11-04 16:05:20.490: E/AndroidRuntime(2196):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: do you know how to look at the logcat?

Comment: Agree with Tim, please post the exception text from LogCat and we will be able to answer your question promptly.

Comment: @Tim 

the logCat is empty, the application crashes when I press a button on the mainActivity

Comment: @WilliamRiley  the logCat is empty, the application crashes when I press a button on the mainActivity

Comment: @ruaa.brkat if it crashed then there will be exceptions in the logcat. Make sure you aren't filtering them out

Comment: what is a DashActivity anyway ?

Comment: `com.example.dashboard_our/com.example.dashboard_our.Hotel` is not in your manifest ...

Comment: @codeMagic I edited the question and added the logcat

Comment: Directly from the log - `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.dashboard_our/com.example.dashboard_our.Hotels}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`  How are you declaring your classes?  Please post the top of your `Hotels` class from the top, down to the first line of `onCreate()`

Comment: @njzk2 you are right, I forgot to add the classes to the Manifest file :)
thank you guys a lot

Comment: @Simon I forgot to add the classes in manifest file, silly me !!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    public void onButtonClicker(View v)
    {
        Intent intent;
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hotels_bt);
            .
            .

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case (b1.getId()):
            intent = new Intent(this, Hotels.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
               .
               .
               .

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```